# Accepted "into" journal?

Tags: prepositions

What is the appropriate way to talk about an article that has been published in a journal? Has it been accepted "into" the journal, "to" the journal, "in" the journal, "by" the journal?

Answer (score 1):

As someone whose wife recently had a paper accepted for publication **by** a journal, I've been hearing that a lot lately. I imagine once the journal is published, she'll be talking about having her paper published **in** the journal.

I guess the determining factor is, do we refer to the journal itself, or the company that publishes it?

Answer (score 0):

"Accepted by the Journal" is correct...here 'Journal' is substituting for the editor or staff of the journal that did the actual accepting.